# how can i mock HttpContextBase to a controller web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
        moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        moqRequest.Setup(x => x.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection {{"email", "bad@gmail.com"}});
        moqRequest.Setup(x => x.HttpMethod).Returns("Get");
        moqRequest.Setup(x => x.Headers).Returns(new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
        {
            {"Host", "localhost"},
            {"Content-MD5", "123456abcd"},
            {"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            {"Date", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)},
        });
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
        ConfidentialeController controller = new ConfidentialeController{ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext()};
```

i can't set my moqContext to constructor HttpControllerContext() two different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to Unit Test a ASP.NET Web API 2 controller, I would suggest you follow the samples in the official docs: [Unit Testing Controllers in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api).

Hope that helps.